# Razor concatinate a string into a URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to concatinate some data in Razor to make a URL with a query string, along the lines of :-

```
<a href= "www.Mysite.com" + "?ID="+ @Html.Raw(m.intItemIdentifier) >  @Html.Raw(m.strItemHeadline) </a><br />
```

and yes I know RAW will bring back unencoded data, and I cannot alter the database.

Comment: You can't add strings together in an HTML tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* the code you show is not rendering the URL you want.

Use either

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?ID=@(Html.Raw(m.intItemIdentifier))">
```

Or

```
<a href="@Html.Raw("http://www.example.com?ID=" + m.intItemIdentifier)">
```

Comment: this works perfectly thanks,  I didnt realise you didnt need to delimit the string.